# How do i display rows and columns in my ruby project?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Im looking to implement a 3 column layout i have the following code in my HTML and CSS code. I have the layout for which i want the container to look like and now i want to add columns but cant seem to get it right for the past couple hours. Any guidance would be grateful and appreciated.

Thank you in advance

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="card radius shadowDepth1">
            <div class="card__image border-tlr-radius">
                <%= link_to image_tag(deal.picture.url(:small), class: "border-tlr-radius") %>
            </div>

            <div class="card__content card__padding">
                <div class="card__share">
                    <div class="card__social">  
                        <a class="share-icon facebook" href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>
                        <a class="share-icon twitter" href="#"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>
                        <a class="share-icon googleplus" href="#"><span class="fa fa-google-plus"></span></a>
                    </div>

                    <a id="share" class="share-toggle share-icon" href="#"></a>
                </div>

                <div class="card__meta">
                    <a href="#">Expires I</a>
                    <%= distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now.utc, deal.end_time) %>
                </div>

                <article class="card__article">

                    <h2 class="#"><%= link_to deal.title, deal, {:style=>'color:#617475;', :class => "css_class"} %></h2>


                    <p> <%= deal.description %></p>
                </article>
            </div>

                <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default"><p> $<%= deal.item_price %></a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-default">$30.00</a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-material-light-green">Buy Now!</a>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


@import 'http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css';
@import 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:700,400';
/*
*  Basic Reset
*/

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/**
 * Basics Styles
 */
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
body {
  background-color: #eee;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #666;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3498db;
}
  a:hover {
    color: #2980b9;
  }

h2 {
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-bottom: 1.6rem;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

/**
 * Helpers
 */
.border-tlr-radius { 
  border-top-left-radius: 2px;
  border-top-right-radius: 2px; 
}

.text-center { text-align: center; }

.radius { border-radius: 2px; }

.padding-tb { padding-top: 1.6rem; padding-bottom: 1.6rem;}

.shadowDepth0 { box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.12); }

.shadowDepth1 {
   box-shadow: 
      0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.12),
      0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0, 0.24);      
}


/**
 * Card Styles
 */

.card {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 1.6rem;
}

.card__padding {
  padding: 1.6rem;
}

.card__image {
  min-height: 100px;
  background-color: #eee;
}
  .card__image img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }

.card__content {
  position: relative;
}

/* card meta */
.card__meta time {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #bbb;
  margin-left: 0.8rem;
}

/* card article */
.card__article a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #444;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
  .card__article a:hover {
    color: #2980b9;
  }

/* card action */
.card__action {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-right: 1.6rem;
  padding-left: 1.6rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.6rem;
}

.card__author {}

  .card__author img,
  .card__author-content {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .card__author img{
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-right: 0.6em;
  }

.card__share {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -42px;
}

.card__social {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateX(0px);
    transition: transform 0.35s ease;
}
  .card__social--active {
    visibility: visible;
    /*z-index: 3;*/
    transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateX(-48px);
      transition: transform 0.35s ease;
  }

.share-toggle {
  z-index: 2;
}
.share-toggle:before {
  content: "\f1e0";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #3498db;
}
  .share-toggle.share-expanded:before {
    content: "\f00d";
  }

.share-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  line-height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  outline: 0;

  box-shadow: 
        0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0, 0.12),
        0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0, 0.24);
}
  .share-icon:hover,
  .share-icon:focus {
    box-shadow: 
        0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0, 0.12),
        0 3px 6px rgba(0,0,0, 0.24);

      -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
      -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
      -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
      -o-transform: scale(1.2);
      transform: scale(1.2);
  }

.facebook {
  background-color: #3b5998; 
}
.twitter {
  background-color: #00abe3; 
}
.googleplus {
  background-color: #d3492c;
}

.facebook,
.twitter,
.googleplus {
  color: #fff;
}

  .facebook:hover,
  .twitter:hover,
  .googleplus:hover {
    color: #eee;
  }

  /// concept ///

  @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700);
@import url(http://weloveiconfonts.com/api/?family=entypo);

/* entypo */
[class*="entypo-"]:before {
  font-family: 'entypo', sans-serif;
}

$primary-text-color: #000;
$secondary-text-color: #A1A1A4;
$theme-color: #8DC63F; 

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;

  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.004);
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.toggler {
  color: $secondary-text-color;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  margin-left: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;

  &.active {
    color: $primary-text-color;
  }
}

.surveys {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

%card-style {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 2px;

  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(170,170,170,0.25);  
}

.survey-item {
  @extend %card-style;
}

.survey-name {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.list {
  .survey-item {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;

    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 40px;

    .pull-right {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
      .stage:not(.active) {
        display: none;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
      .survey-progress-bg {
        display: none;
      }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      .pull-right {
        position: static;
        line-height: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
      }
    }
  }

  .survey-country,
  .survey-progress,
  .survey-completes,
  .survey-end-date {
    color: $secondary-text-color;
  }

  .survey-country,
  .survey-completes,
  .survey-end-date,
  .survey-name,
  .survey-stage {
    margin: 0 10px;
  }

  .survey-country {
    margin-right: 0;
  }

  .survey-end-date,
  .survey-completes,
  .survey-country,
  .survey-name {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }

  .survey-end-date {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;

    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

.survey-stage .stage {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;

  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 2px;

  background: #f2f2f2;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  color: transparent;
  line-height: 16px;

  &.active {
    background: $secondary-text-color;
  }
}

.list {
  .list-only {
    display: auto;
  }
  .grid-only {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

.grid {
  .grid-only {
    display: auto;
  }
  .list-only {
    display: none !important;
  }
}

.grid {
  .survey-item {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 200px;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 10px;

    @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
      display: block;
      width: auto;
      height: 150px;
      margin: 10px auto;
    }
  }

  .survey-name {
    display: block;
    max-width: 80%;

    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }

  .survey-country {
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .survey-country,
  .survey-end-date {
    color: $secondary-text-color;
  }

  .survey-end-date {
    &:before {
      content: 'Ends\00a0';
    }

    &.ended:before {
      content: 'Ended\00a0';
    }
  }

  .survey-progress {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    font-size: 13px;
  }

  .survey-progress-bg {
    width: 40%;
    display: block;

    @media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
      display: none;
    }
  }

  .survey-progress-labels {
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 40px;

    @media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
      right: auto;
      left: 10px;
    }    
  }

  .survey-progress-label {
    line-height: 21px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 400;
  }

  .survey-completes {
    line-height: 21px;
    font-size: 13px;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }  

  .survey-stage {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;

    .stage {
      display: none;
    }

    .active {
      display: block;
    }
  }

  .survey-end-date {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
  }
}

.survey-progress-label {
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 10px;
  color: $theme-color;
}

.survey-progress-bg {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #eee;
}

.survey-progress-fg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: $theme-color;
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Right now they are showing as a long list. I'm just trying to make that post's display as columns like this , thank you http://samara.computer/531_adaptive/startbootstrap-master/startbootstrap-master/2-col-portfolio.php

Comment: What post? There is no post in your question?

Comment: Lol.. Ok so the application I'm building displays post's kind of like what you see on dribble.  So i want those thumbnails of post's not to display as a long list but as columns. Sorry for the confusion should've wrote the question with more detail was half asleep.

Comment: So basically right i have an app that is displaying a list of post's but they are formatted to show as a single column but i want it show as formatted with 3 columns

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's great that you've included your code - this is helpful and just what we need to be able to debug. However it'd also be really good for you to show us an example of the resulting output html/css - preferably in some kind of fiddle so we can play with it and make it work for you. Can you do that, then provide us a link?